# How to store in cookie a list with objects MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, c#-3.0

I need to store the shopping list items in cookie.
I have the products page where each product has an "Add" button where it should be added to cookie.
I run into a problem, I observed that I can store in the cookie only one product. If the user wants to add the second product to the basket, the first product will be overwrite with the newly added product.

I didn't find any solution on the net which can help me, my question is: I can store a list of objects in the cookie.

I tried this way:

```
string myObjectJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(cartItem);

var cookiea = new HttpCookie("myObjectKey", myObjectJson)
{
  Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
};
```

When I need the cookie value, I can get this way. It works:

```
var tttt = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ShoppingCartVM>(myObjectJson);
```

How should I resolve the problem if the cookie already contains an item, to add a the new item to the same cookie, meaning the cookie had to store a list of objects, and when I need it to return me the entire list of the objects?
Could anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you save the whole list? I can see you serialize cartItem variable. The name suggests you really save only one item.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The example from code really saves one item, but the question was how can I save an object list to cookie, adding a new item to a cookie which contains already some elements. I need to save the whole list, because this should be the shopping list, which can contain more elements, whenever the user press the Add button from a product, it should be added to shopping list, in my case in the cookie. And when the user press the Shopping Cart button, there I should retrieve the whole list from the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use Cookies for storing shopping cart items. Session is much better in this case. Cookies are stored on the client side whereas Session is stored on server. When you use cookies, you send whole serialized shopping cart back and forth between the client and server, that's not necessary. Also, Cookies's size is limited and Session does allow you to store complex objects.

To save the shopping cart, use (in controller):

```
ShoppingCartVM cart; // create instance of the shopping cart
this.Session["ShoppingCart"] = cart;
```

To get the values, use:

```
if (this.Session["ShoppingCart"] !== null) 
{
    ShoppingCartVM cart = (ShoppingCartVM)Session["NeededByDateTime"]; 
}
```

If you need something persistent. To make sure that the user will find their products in the cart even after couple months. You should consider saving their shopping cart in database.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I guess I will use session to store the shopping cart items.